# How to fix error when pivoting a datafame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have data in a dataframe that looks like this in this structure:

```
Item   Count    Date
    A   5       25-May-18
    B   5       25-May-18
    C   5       25-May-18
    A   6       24-May-18
    B   6       24-May-18
    C   6       24-May-18
    A   7       23-May-18
    B   7       23-May-18
    C   7       23-May-18
```

I am looking for the data to be structured this way:

```
Date        A   B   C
25-May-18   5   5   5
24-May-18   6   6   6
23-May-18   7   7   7
```

Here is my code:

```
dropped_col.pivot_table(dropped_col, values = 'count', index='date', columns = 'item').reset_index()
```

But I get an error:

> in ()
>   ----> 1 dropped_col.pivot_table(dropped_col, values = 'count', index='date', columns = 'item').reset_index()
>
> TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'

Any suggestions on what I can do help solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: pivot != transpose

Comment: I found my answer located here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134486/typeerror-pivot-table-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-values